# Laravel - retrieval of log info to display on view

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm trying to keep a Log of all the activities that a user performs (from clicking on Login button to all the CRUD operation) in my application.

Eg - When the user clicks on a 'Create Item' button I wish to log info(when it was created, what was created, by whom etc.) in a separate file under /storage/logs/my_own_file.log.

I have been able to do that using the Log::info and Log:useDailyFiles() function.

Now whatever information I wish to display from the Log files, should come on some view(assume a random view page). I have thought of extracting the Log files info in JSON format so that I can pass that variable in the view.

I don't know how to go about it as of now.

[This the Log file when I click on the Edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzwId.png)

[This is the Log file when I click the Submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG75a.png)

For the time being assume, I want the timestamps(individually) and the id as JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider storing an activity log in a database instead of the files, you won't be stuck parsing that way. I use this package on several of my projects:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

This gives you much more flexibility in what you save and how deep in the application stack you can access.

Comment: I see. @btl I have run into another problem. Let's say I'm storing the logs in a file as of now. Now I want to get each line of the log and wish to store each data of every line in a separate variable.

Comment: Eg.
[date] [time] [info] [id]

I wish to extract these from each line and store them into their respective variables FOR EACH LINE , so that, they can be displayed on the view for every line. I'm having problem with the loops 

    `$file = fopen(storage_path().'/logs/updated-2017-06-15.log',"r");

    $b = '';

    while(! feof($file))
    {
    $b = $b.''.fgets($file);

    }

    $d = explode("\n",$b);

    // $a = $d[0];
    //
    // $e = substr($a,0,10);
    // echo $e; `

I wish to make a 'foreach' loop but I'm not getting how to.

Comment: Before you get too deep down that path, would a package work for you? You can install this within your laravel application and it will read the log files for you and present them very nicely in the browser.


https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer

Comment: Can it also integrated onto a production environment. I am just concerned about having a hard time trying to configure something new. I'll install it and see how it works though. Will get back to you once done and in case I have any issues!
Thanks :)

Comment: If you lock the routes down with the proper authorization it would be fine on a live server, although it isn't something i would do personally. parsing log files just sounds like hell to me

Comment: I have configured it according to my system. It shows something like this.

http://imgur.com/a/vIGxp

Now I want to send the Id , user name, date, time etc under different columns as a view. How do I go about it?.. Please tell me if you don't understand my query. I'll send a dummy screenshot of what I'm expecting

Comment: Does that package publish any of its resource files? Are you able to override any views and customize to your needs?

Comment: I forgot to carry out the view customization configuration thing. Let me do that and get back to you!!

Comment: I have managed to customize the view according to my needs. But now I want it to be a specific view page for every activity or operation I carry out.

Eg. For Updated log, this is my customization

http://imgur.com/a/NJdhA

But the same customization is being applied to Edit one also. This is how it looks 

http://imgur.com/a/Sk3gz

This is happening because there is a common view for both. I wish to have individual pages for each. I'm not able to find from where the log.blade.php view is being called.

Comment: Its got to be in the vendor directory someone, check for a resouces/view directory first and then try a find for the word blade

Comment: I found it and have managed to configure it for the application. Now I only wish to know how I wish put it for production when the need arises. Will I have to install the package on the server too and configure it accordingly.